# Rails 4 - Coffeescript not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, stripe-payments

I'm building a marketplace app where sellers can list items to sell. I created a form where users can submit bank account info so payments can be transferred. The form works and submits but the coffeescript used to create the bank account token doesn't seem to fire.

I had this working when the bank info was being collected as part of the listing form. I wanted it on a separate page so I moved it to the user controller.

I also disabled turbolinks on the link to this page.

Here is my edit user form:

```
<h3>Edit Bank Account Details</h3>
<%= form_for @user, url: user_path, html: { method: :put } do |f| %>
     <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %><i> (as it appears in your bank account)</i>
      <%= f.text_field :bankaccname, class:"form-control" %>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :country %>
      <%= text_field_tag :country, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "country", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :routing_number %>
      <%= text_field_tag :routing_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "routingNumber", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :account_number %>
      <%= text_field_tag :account_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "accountNumber", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
     </div>

<% end %>
```

my user.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  user.setupForm()

user =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#edit_user').submit ->
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
        Stripe.bankAccount.createToken($('#edit_user'), user.handleStripeResponse)
        false

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#edit_user').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(response.id))
      $('#edit_user')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show()
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

Here is my update method in the user_controller:

```
   def update

    Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
      token = params[:stripeToken]

      recipient = Stripe::Recipient.create(
        :name => current_user.bankaccname,
        :type => "individual",
        :bank_account => token
        )

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_url, notice: 'Your account was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you verified that the form really is `#edit-user`? Have you verified that `user.setupForm` gets called?

Comment: The route prefix for the form is edit_user. Isn't that the name I should be using? How do I verify setupForm is called? users.js is being called per the logs.

Comment: You can look at the HTML to verify the `id`. You can throw in a quick `console.log` call to see if `setupForm` is called. You might want to read [the Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js?#bank-account-createToken) too.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks! i checked html and saw that I was calling the #edit_user. I changed it call the class as .edit_user and the stripe token was created.